# Return array of List Box Items that match criteria - Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I currently have this set up for a `ListView`. However wondered if there's a similar way to do it using a `ListBox`. I would like to return an array of items that matches a criteria (in this case, return items in the listbox that match `applicationName`, which is a string).

I've included what works for my list view:

```
    Dim listviewitem As ListViewItem
    Dim ListViewItems() As ListViewItem = Me.ApplicationsListView.Items.Find(applicationName, True)

    For Each listviewitem In ListViewItems
        listviewitem.Checked = True
    Next
```

The reason I can't seem to get this working with a `ListBox` is that it doesn't have a `Find` method for `Me.ApplicationsListBox.Items`. Wondering if there's a similar method for list boxes.

Comment: `[ListBox].FindString()` / `[ListBox].FindStringExact()`

Comment: Should this return an array? I'm getting an `Expression is of type int` when I try to loop this.

Comment: It returns the index of the string found. Or `ListBox.NoMatches` if the string was not found. You can use the overload that allows to specify the starting index, which is set to the index previously found (use a variable to store the indexes).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks! I'll give this a go and change around the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method that will return all items with the specific text in a `ListBox` as an enumerable list:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module ListBoxExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Iterator Function Find(source As ListBox, value As String) As IEnumerable(Of Object)
        Dim items = source.Items

        For i = 0 To items.Count - 1
            Dim item = items(i)

            If source.GetItemText(item) = value Then
                Yield item
            End If
        Next
    End Function

End Module
```

Here is some sample usage:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add(1, "Peter")
            .Add(2, "Paul")
            .Add(3, "Mary")
            .Add(4, "Peter")
        End With

        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ListBox1.DataSource = table
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim peters = ListBox1.Find("Peter").ToArray()

        For Each row As DataRowView In peters
            Console.WriteLine(row("Id"))
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

That *Output* window will display the following when debugging that code:

```
1
4
```

You can use that code as is or adapt the principle as you like. You pass modify the method to accept a predicate and then match any way you like. You can modify the code to use directly in your form instead of as an extension if you prefer. It's the principle that matters.